# Validate Input for Text field in Screen flow is not working

Tags: validation, salesforce, formula, screen, salesforce-flow

I am trying to Validate input of text field conditionally. But its not working. When i debug the flow it's not validating the input.

I've tried ISBLANK(), ISNULL() also but no use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to make required field cmt then it will work validation. In your case for conditional you need to make decision element testpick was selected "other" also you need to assignment element set variable flag true. then loop back to same screen. then below cmt you need to add display message there you need to put error message it display when flag is true then display message.